# What is the difference between an object proposal and an object boundary in Computer Vision?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, deep-learning, object-detection

In Computer Vision, what is difference between an object proposal and other (object boundary, object region, bounding box, contour)?

Answer (score 1):

Object proposal: indicating that how likely current region contains object.

Object boundary: is similar to edges. The difference between boundary and edge is that boundary has object level information and edges are usually scattered.

Bounding box: provided by user to indicate specific information, such as object.

Contour: is also similar to edges. However, it has no object level information. One contour can consist of edges of different objects.